# How is it possible for a computer to calculate PI to a specific certainty?

Tags: java

It seems like every single algorithm I can find is an infinite series.

Take for example the Chudnovsky algorithm:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlGl6.png]

As you can see, to calculate the kth digit of PI, I have to go through an infinite series. However, computers have a finite amount of processing power. So how is it possible to write a program that can calculate PI to any arbitrary amount (k) of decimal places?

Comment: That type of infinite sum converges on an answer, so you can keep iterating and get more and more precise results.

Comment: You can't calculate an infinite number of decimal place s in finite time.  But you don't need to.  If you know you want k decimal places you only need to calculate enough terms so that the uncalculated terms are smaller than the kth decimal place.

Comment: (In other words, [like he did](http://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each term in the infinite series provides a small refinement to the value of pi estimated by the previous iteration.  That is, the estimated value of pi converges upon the actual value.

As long as (k) is a finite number, you can calculate successive terms of the infinite series until the first (k) digits of the estimated value of pi are stable (they do not change upon successive iterations).

Comment: Makes sense. I just need a minimum of two iterations where the digits are the same to conclude that they are stable, right?

Comment: @user2939787 For the vast majority of convergent series, yes.